# Learning Git and branching, but already up-to-date

Tags: git, github

After taking a look into Git, I tried to understand how branching in practice would work.

Somehow when I try to merge a change from one branch to the master branch, my terminal will return a message saying that master branch is already up-to-date. When I look in Github it still is showing the old code and I also do not see the branch I just made by executing:

```
git branch {branchnamehere}
```

command.

Can anyone explain me how I should run my commands properly to understand how branching works? Is there anything I am doing incorrectly?

This pastebin shows you what I tried to execute: [Pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/mh1t3mZS).

If there is anything missing in my question which one of you would require to know, please let me know and I will edit the question.

**Edit:** So basically when you make a change in (for example) your master branche, you are wiling to run:

```
git pull
```

or

```
git fetch
```

If changes are okay,

```
git merge
```

(the above part is only for retreiving files from remote repository and merge them with local repository)

```
git add -A
git commit -m "commitmessage goes here, make it a clear one"
git push
```

And everything should show correctly on the remote repository afterwards. If one makes an new branch you would like to run:

```
git checkout newbranch
```

or if it does not exist (yet):

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git push
```

So you will push that branch to remote repository instead of master, just make sure you check out the desired branch before pushing. This is what I learned out of the answers below, thanks to you!

Comment: I'm not going to give a formal answer, because your question is a bit vague, but my guess as to what is happening is that you are not synching with the remote repository.  This is the reason why `master` appears to be up-to-date: it is, with the branch you have locally, even though that branch has changed on the remote.

Comment: So your generally strategy should be to do `git fetch` _before_ you attempt anything, and then `git push` to sync what you have done locally with the remote.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Would it be bad to do `git pull` instead of `git fetch`? I just learned that `git pull` is (probably exectly) the same as running `git fetch` and `git merge` right after that.

Comment: You just answered your own question: the only additional thing which `git pull` will do is to merge the remote tracking branch into your local branch.  Which one you choose depends on the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very cool game which will teach you all about branching, cherry-pick revert and more.

http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

> #### Interested in learning Git?
>
> Well you've come to the right place! "Learn Git Branching" is the most visual and interactive way to learn Git on the web; you'll be challenged with exciting levels, given step-by-step demonstrations of powerful features, and maybe even have a bit of fun along the way.

---

#### How to merge changes?

> Somehow when I try to merge a change from one branch to the master branch

Several options:

```
# grab the latest code from the server   
git fetch --all --prune

# checkout the desired branch if you're not already using it 
git checkout <branch>
# merge the 2 branches
git merge origin/master

# ----
# use the pull command which does fetch+merge
git checkout <branch>
git pull origin/master
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing such interesting tool. I will see if I can pick anything up there.

Comment: I tried out this tool and it gives a clear visual way of showing what is going on. Is it not that in practice there are no visuals available for what is going on? How can I tell how my tree would look like or what the differences between branches are without any visual window showing commits and branches etc.?

Comment: Well I just finished it and I guess the whole visual thing was more to make clear what happens when you run what command. Still don't know much about git init. Anyways thanks https://i.gyazo.com/11dd985316618299635ecde11682fd14.png

Comment: Hi.  Il get back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You've tried to merge the master into your branch. Since you've probably created the branch out of master and since that time the master wasn't updated you've got this message.

In order to merge your changes back to master you should (after committing your changes into yourbranch):

```
git checkout master 
git merge <yourbranch>
```

This is the most obvious way to merge your changes back to master branch.

Now all this stuff happens locally on your machine, its the main difference between Git and centralized source control systems like Subversion.

So even after you've merged the changes to master you won't see anything on GitHub.

If you need to push the changes upstream to GitHub, you should:

```
git push
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out. I still wonder why I won't be seeing my added branch though.

Answer (score 1):

When you're typing your merge command you are still on the branch companyinfo, which means you are merging master with companyinfo. You haven't changed anything within the master branch since you made your companyinfo branch so your companyinfo is up to date.
You need to ensure you are on the master branch first, as the git merge command merges into the current branch.
   git checkout master
Checkout will switch your branch.
and then from master you merge in the changes in companyinfo
   git merge companyinfo

Comment: Yes I got to understand this from the answer of Mark Bramnik. Thank you for the explanation.